# Oracle SQL - Find Consecutive Values on Consecutive Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a query to find 3 or more consecutive occurrence of a value (Refer Column Flag) and it must happen on consecutive dates.The query should not pick values if the occurrence doesn't happen on consecutive dates For e.g

```
COLUMN ID   DATE            FLAG
100         10-JUL-2015     Y
100         11-JUL-2015     Y
100         12-JUL-2015     Y
100         13-JUL-2015     N
100         14-JUL-2015     Y
100         15-JUL-2015     Y
100         16-JUL-2015     N
100         17-JUL-2015     Y
100         18-JUL-2015     Y
100         19-JUL-2015     Y
100         20-JUL-2015     Y
100         21-JUL-2015     Y
```

OUTPUT

```
COLUMN ID   DATE            FLAG
100         10-JUL-2015     Y
100         11-JUL-2015     Y
100         12-JUL-2015     Y
100         17-JUL-2015     Y
100         18-JUL-2015     Y
100         19-JUL-2015     Y
100         20-JUL-2015     Y
100         21-JUL-2015     Y
```

Any Idea to accomplish this in Oracle SQL. I am trying to use analytic functions like LAG and LEAD but unable to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a very handy trick.  The groups of consecutive values can be calculated using a difference of `row_number()`s.  Then, you need to get the count for each group and select the ones that match your condition:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id, flag, grp) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by id order by date) -
                    row_number() over (partition by id, flag order by date)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3;
```

Strictly speaking, you do not need the difference of `row_numbers()`.  Assuming your dates have no time components, the following will also suffice:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id, flag, grp) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   (date -
                    row_number() over (partition by id, flag order by date)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3;
```

Comment: I'm  trying to do the same using `RANK` instead. But I test your code in my [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c10bd/1) and didnt run. Maybe you would like to check.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . The table and columns just need to have the right names:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c10bd/6.

Comment: I think this will not work for the following case:

COLUMN ID   DATE            FLAG
100         10-JUL-2015     Y
100         11-JUL-2015     Y
100         12-JUL-2015     Y
100        15-JUL-2015 Y

In the below scenario, the query still fetches rows for 15-JUL-2015 Which it shouldnt

Comment: @Sandy . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  I think it works in that case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -  actually it works if we check for 3 consecutive dates. what about 4 consecutive dates. I was running the same by using the criteria for 4 consecutive dates and it was fetching 10, 11, 12, 15 even 12 and 15th july are not consecutive days. ideally it should not fetch any rows. any help to resolve is highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: To Clarify

If the data set looks something like this below:

ID   DATE  FLAG
10000000 12-JAN-16 Y
10000000 13-JAN-16 Y
10000000 14-JAN-16 Y
10000000 19-JAN-16 Y
10000000 20-JAN-16 Y
10000000 21-JAN-16 Y

The following query will still fetch the output.

SELECT T.*
FROM (SELECT T.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, FLAG, GRP) AS CNT
      FROM (SELECT T.*,
                   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) -
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, FLAG ORDER BY DATE)
                   ) AS GRP
            FROM TABLE T
           ) T
     ) T
WHERE CNT >= 4;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This makes use of recursive common table expressions and `lead` analytical function.

```
with x as
(select id, mydate, flag from table1 where flag = 'Y')
, y as(select id, mydate, lead(mydate) over(order by mydate) as nxt,flag from x)
, z as (select id, mydate, nxt, lead(nxt) over(order by nxt) as nxt_1,flag from y)
select distinct t.id, t.mydate,t.flag from z
join x t on z.id = t.id 
and (t.mydate = z.mydate or t.mydate = z.nxt or t.mydate = z.nxt_1)
where z.nxt-z.mydate = 1 and z.nxt_1-z.nxt =1
order by t.mydate
```

SQLfiddle with test data
 : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bbed/1