# Consecutive records in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a similar question thought to post here. 
Need Employees who were absent for 3 or more consecutive days. Assume all the days are working days no holidays on Saturday/Sunday/Anyother days.

In the table below I need 20342123 and 20311111 in the result set. 
Employee 20311333 has taken 4 leaves but they are not consecutive.

Thanks for help in advance.

```
Emp Id     |  AsofDate      | Comment 
----------------------------------
20342123   |  1-JAN-2017| Absent 
20342123   |  2-JAN-2017| Absent 
20342123   |  3-JAN-2017| Absent
20311111   |  1-JAN-2017| Absent 
20311111   |  2-JAN-2017| Absent 
20311111   |  3-JAN-2017| Absent
20311333   |  5-JAN-2017| Absent
20311333   |  6-JAN-2017| Absent
20311333   |  8-JAN-2017| Absent 
20311333   |  9-JAN-2017| Absent
20322222   |  1-JAN-2017| Absent
20322222   |  2-JAN-2017| Absent
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can apply a "gaps-and-islands" solution, I think `lag()`/`lead()` is simpler for this problem:

```
select distinct emp_id
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by empid order by date) as date_1,
             lead(date, 2) over (partition by empid order by date) as date_2
      from t
      where comment = 'Absent'  -- not sure if this is important
     ) t
where date_1 = date + 1 and date_2 = date + 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff.  I missed one point there. Correct question is '3 or MORE consecutive occurrences...' .   Yes  comment = 'Absent' is required as other values will also be there.

Comment: @DevadasWagle . . . This finds 3 in a row.  Hence it finds 3 or more in a row.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working even for 3 consecutive rows. I know that there are records in the table but does not appear in the output.

Comment: Gordon Linoff :  I searched similar one here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660093/oracle-sql-find-consecutive-values-on-consecutive-dates?rq=1    But there also the user says the query is not working when we want that for more than 3 successive occurrences.

Comment: @DevadasWagle . . . Is it possible that your `date` column has a time component?

Comment: Gordon Linoff.. I have added the TRUNC(record_ins_date). If I want to change the query to work like 7 or more days instead of 3 or more days.. then what do I need to change there?  Thanks for help.

Comment: @DevadasWagle . . . You could add 6 lags.  There are other ways to do this  . . . but your question is *explicitly* about 3 days.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *question* and not a comment.